# NSBundle pathforResource, where to place movie file

Tags: iphone, nsbundle

I'm not quite sure how pathForResource works.  I wanted to play a movie from my app.  I dragged it into XCode, checking the box to add it to subfolders and create directory if needed.  I placed it in a separate folder called Videos.  There is no Resources folder for this app (someone deleted it and thought it would be better to just have folders for each type of resource (img, vid, etc).  So I'm not sure where to drop my movie, and how to access it using the NSBundle methods.  This is what I have, but it does not seem to play.

```
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"];  
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];  
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 120, 300, 200)];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                               object:moviePlayerController];  
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
    [moviePlayerController play];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this code should list everything in your mainBundle

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
NSArray *files = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.m4v'"]];
NSLog(@"Directory Start");
NSLog(@"%@",dirContents);
NSLog(@"Directory End");
NSLog(@"files: %@",files);
```

Or you could just go to the ~user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator and find you app and right click on it and show the content to see the directory structure of your app.

Comment: if I can NSLog the filepath, then I am assuming my path is correct right?  Otherwise the NSString would be nil right?  So it must be something I'm doing wrong in playing the movie right?  Thanks.

Comment: You should put in an if statement to check if the file exist. `if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) { // Check to see if file exist // do something }`